# Just to specific loop index when debugging

Tags: matlab, loops, debugging

MATLAB has some convenient features which help to ease debugging the code with function calls, like the following:

- `"step"` to execute a line without showing function body instructions.
- `"step in"` to navigate to the corresponding function body if possible.
- `"continue"` as usually executes code lines until next breakpoint.

Is there any way (or hack, as I found no option found in the debugger tools) to speed through loop iterations to a desired index? Manual iterating through pixels' indices within images at larger than 300x300 in size is an absurd waste of time.

Let's say I want to quickly reach a specific index in the following loop, for example `x=50` and `y=90`:

```
for x=leftxlimit:rightxlimit
    for y=topylimit:botylimit
        if (toplayers2(y,x) == 0)
            ...
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use [conditional breakpoints](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/set-breakpoints.html#buvvmfu-1)

Set a breakpoint within your loop, right click and select "Set/Modify Condition".

Then you can set the condition "`x == 50 && y == 50`" (or whatever else) using the workspace variables and standard MATLAB expressions.

This way, you can run the code normally (without stepping) and it will stop on that line if and only if the condition is true.

If you want to stop on a line for multiple `x` or `y` values, simply phrase your condition to be true on those values like `x == 50 && y >= 50 && y <= 60` for example.

Comment: You can also set breakpoints programatically using `dbstop`: `dbstop in FILESPEC at LINENO if EXPRESSION`.